# Compiling OpenCV 3.2 on Linux Mint 20.2 / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, linux-mint, ubuntu-20.04, opencv3.2

I'm trying to compile OpenCV 3.2 in my Mint 20.2 machine. I've been trying for several weeks now and had no success. I keep running into some breaks or crashes during compilation. I've already tried enabling/disabling a few flags that at first seemed to be problematic. But when one break appears to be solved, a new one comes out.

So for a fresh start and see If someone can give me a hint, this is what I'm doing now:

**1)** Following the steps published [here](https://www.itsfoss.net/how-to-install-and-configure-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/) for downloading the sources from Git and `git checkout` to version 3.2.0

**2)** Cmake and configure using:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \ 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \ 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \ 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Output of the configuring step: [here](https://pastebin.com/6tHBE5iS)

**3)** `make -j8` on the build folder

**4).** Error during compilation: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wb2Y.png)

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please don't use version 3.2. use a recent release. if you don't need to use OpenCV from C++, scrap all of this and simply install `opencv-python` for python, using `pip`. -- and *do not* post screenshots of text. post the text itself.

Comment: Hi Christoph. I apologize for the screenshots. Its my first time posting on Stack. Wont happen again. About OpenCV version, I strongly need  version 3.2 installed since it works as a dependency for another software that doesnt run with the newest version. I know that installing from the repo or opencv-python would be easier but unfortunaly it is not what I need.

Comment: try disabling the `viz` module. set `BUILD_opencv_viz` to false (cmake).

Comment: From deleted link-only answer in case it helps: [OpenCV3.2withContrib.sh](https://gist.github.com/syneart/3e6bb68de8b6390d2eb18bff67767dcb)